# (Go/carry/keep) on VS continue

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, verbs, word-difference

According to the dictionaries, these four verbs have so many practical overlaps as well as some semantic nuances which restricts my understanding as a non-native speaker to use the natural verb in each case.

Sometimes I face some situations where some natives switch between these similar verbs in the similar situations. {it strikes me like that, but I'm sure there is a lingual reason behind their usage} and this is why I came to this question so that could find out the logic behind it.

I wonder if you could give me a hand to figure it out so that I could come to a conclusion about these similar concepts.

Please consider my examples and help me to fill in the following blanks where I'm struggling to find the fitting verbs for each sentence:

> 1- No matter what the sorrounding people say or ask from you................the way you're going. Everyone, wants you the way they like. (self-made sentence) [verb + noun phrase]

a) go on 
 
b) carry on 
c) continue 
d) keep on

> 2- That's a great story....................... [imperative, stand alone form of the verb]

a) go on 
 
b) carry on 
c) continue 
d) keep on

> 3- Even though the athlete was injured, he.................running. [verb + verb + ing]

a) go on 
 
b) carry on 
c) continue 
d) keep on

Thank you.